# Trying to pass a subdirectory as a parameter in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a Perl program to read .html's and only works if the program is in the same directory as the .html's.
I would like to be able to start in different directories and pass the html's location as a parameter.  The program (shell example below) traverses the subdirectory "sub" 
and its subdirectories to look for .html's, but only works when my perl file is in the same subdirectory "sub".  If I put the Perl file 
in the home directory, which is one step back from the subdirectory "sub", it doesn't work.

In the shell, if I type "perl project.pl ./sub" from my home directory, it says could 
not open ./sub/file1.html. No such file or directory.  Yet the file does exist in that exact spot. 
file1.html is the first file it is trying to read.

If I change directories in the shell to that subdirectory and move the .pl file 
there and then say in the shell: "perl project.pl ./" everything is ok.

To search the directories, I have been using the File::Find concept which I found here:
[How to traverse all the files in a directory; if it has subdirectories, I want to traverse files in subdirectories too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600395/how-to-traverse-all-the-files-in-a-directory-if-it-has-subdirectories-i-want-t)
[Find::File to search a directory of a list of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295665/findfile-to-search-a-directory-of-a-list-of-files)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

find( \&directories, $ARGV[0]);

sub directories {
    $_ = $File::Find::name;

    if(/.*\.html$/){#only read file on local drive if it is an .html
        my $file = $_;
        open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";
        while(my $line = <$info>)  {   

        #perform operations on file
        }
        close $info;
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [documentation of File::Find](https://metacpan.org/module/RJBS/perl-5.16.3/lib/File/Find.pm#The-wanted-function) it says:

> You are chdir()'d to $File::Find::dir when the function is called,
>   unless no_chdir was specified. Note that when changing to directories
>   is in effect the root directory (/) is a somewhat special case
>   inasmuch as the concatenation of $File::Find::dir, '/' and $_ is not
>   literally equal to $File::Find::name.

So you actually are at `~/sub` already. Only use the filename, which is `$_`. You do not need to overwrite it. Remove the line:

```
$_ = $File::Find::name;
```

Answer (score 1):

`find` changes directory automatically so that `$File::Find::name` is no longer relative to the current directory.

You can delete this line to get it to work:

```
$_ = $File::Find::name;
```

See also [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) `no_chdir`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/module/RJBS/perl-5.16.3/lib/File/Find.pm) documentation:

> For each file or directory found, it calls the &wanted subroutine.
>   (See below for details on how to use the &wanted function).
>   Additionally, for each directory found, *it will chdir() into that
>   directory* and continue the search, invoking the &wanted function on
>   each file or subdirectory in the directory.

(emphasis mine)

The reason it's not finding `./sub/file1.html` is because, when `open` is called, File::Find has already `chdir`ed you into `./sub/`.  You should be able to open the file as just `file1.html`.